# Swift 3 - declaration no longer allowed

Tags: swift3

I have this code (he old 2.3 version used NSDictionary I believe although I am getting mildly confused after having fixed the first 1000 conversion issues):

```
var attr_opt: Dictionary? = nil;
do { 
  attr_opt = try FMainFileManager.aributesOfItem(aPath: APath);
}
catch {
}
```

Xcode claims error

> nil cannot initialize specificed Dictionary?

and suggests using `Dicionary??`

Can anyone explain why the original declaration no longer works? And what is the best way to convert if necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have say what kind of dictionary it is, that is, specify the type of its keys and the type of its values, e.g. `[String:String]?` or `[String:Any]?` or similar.

The most *general* possible type, corresponding to a nullable NSDictionary, would be `[AnyHashable:Any]?`. But it is best to be as *specific* as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I have included more code now. I will try to fix code to "var attr_opt: [FileAttributeKey:Any]? = nil;"